# Title: Error in JMeter while running jmeter.bat

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I download Latest JMeter verserion from https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi (Version 5.1.1). After extracting to my primary drive from command prompt run jmeter.bat which results below error.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/JMeter/lib/ApacheJMeter_slf4j_logkit.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/JMeter/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.jmeter.logging.LogkitLoggerFactory]
```

java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.log.Logger

java -versoin command shows JRE 12.0.1 (64 Bit)
JAVA_HOME is properly in my PC.

Can I any one tell what is missing to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you accept answer if it helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has two SLF4J bindings :

1. C:/JMeter/lib/ApacheJMeter_slf4j_logkit.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
2. C:/JMeter/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class

Try again to run jmeter.bat by removing the first one.

You can refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDvJSzNWJdQ&list=PLkkGqdBS1r094KcNXRy4Q-v5biuNWv-h7&index=1) for JMeter installation and setup!